# React Native Android Run Problem with Stucking Old Version without Re-bundling Each Time on MacOS

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile, mobile-development

I could not run the project on the Android without re-bundling each time I want to run my changes. Here is the re-bundling command:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

After that I could not use `react-native run-android` because simply it could not find any emulator or physical device however I can find my emulators or devices via `adb devices`.

When I use `react-native run-android` it has some errors on the log.

[Could not find adb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnh9O.png)

[image: ADB Problem]

It says, 'could not find any device or emulator' and could find the the ADB. However, both directory and devices are okay. I've checked them like 100 times. Therefore, I could not use the command!

I have to use `Android Studio` to run the project on Emulator or Physical Devices. It works but each time I have to change thing, I have to re-bundle whole android project. Reset the Bundler's cache and then re-run on Android Studio to see my changes. It just kills me :(

I need a solution for better development on Android with React Native. 
Additional information: I'm working on MacOS. I literally tried everything on the internet but could not find the solution for me.

Comment: If you're running in the Android Studio emulator, you should be able to just type RR on the keyboard (if the emulator has focus) for it to reload

Comment: Also,have you run : `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Comment: It reload but it does not load the new changes. Stuck with the old version. Only re-bundling command fixes it.

Comment: Tried the adb reverse command. Not worked :(

Comment: Ok.   `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` needs to work for the reload to work.  Once it's working, then restart the emulator.

Comment: If you're getting a  ENOENT then the path to adb isn't getting set correctly

Comment: Okay, actually adb reverse worked for the Fast Refresh now however, do I need to use this command for each run? Do we have a permanent solution?

Comment: I've set the ADB from my zshrc & even on Genymotion correctly. How could I test it?

Comment: you do not need it for each run - it will run as long as the shell is running

Comment: Okay, at least I have a much better solution now :) Thank you so much @MikeM :)

Comment: I know it's irrelevant but do you know the solution for FlatList's scrollable problem for Android?

Comment: sorry, no. prob best to open another SO question.  good luck

Comment: adb devices are connect?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to yours regarding running build from command line, found solution in this post https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23282#issuecomment-476439080

**Edit**: 
This solution concerns ios

Comment: This is an old problem for iOS. I have the problem on Android